# How to add two columns from three different files with reference to matching values in another column?

Tags: bash

File 1:

```
1  0.3
2  0.1
3  0.4
4  0.8
```

File a:

```
2  0.7
4  0.2
6  0.5
8  0.9
```

File b:

```
2 0.4
6 0.6
```

#### Goal

Step-by-step:

1. Find common values in field 1 ($1) between Files 1, a, and b. As a sample solution to the above files:

   - File 1, File a, and File b all have a common value in $1 = 2.
   - File 1 and File a also have a common value in $1 = 4
2. Output File 1, with the following changes:

   - For $1 = 2, then $2 = 0.1 + 0.7 + 0.4 = 1.2
   - For $1 = 4, then $2 = 0.8 + 0.2 = 1.0

Desired output in File 2:

```
1 0.3
2 1.2
3 0.4
4 1.0
```

Namely, File 2 = File 1, except the rows, where $1 in File 1 matches $1 in File a or b, have been added together in $2.

#### similar problem

I have already received [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002279/how-to-add-two-columns-from-two-different-files-with-reference-to-matching-value) on this problem for matching and adding two files, using the code

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {$2=$1 in a?$2+a[$1]:$2} 1' Input_file2  Input_file1 >> output_file
```

However, the code cannot process 3 input files simultaneously. If I do them separately (two files at a time, ie. File 1 + File a, then File 1 + File b), I end up adding File 1's value twice.

As I potentially have 3-6 files to compare, I cannot simply do File a + File b >> File c, followed by File 1 + File c >> File 2.

#### Summary

I would like a script that can search for matches in $1 between three files, then print $2 (File 1) + $2 (File a and/or File b) wherever a $1 match is found. The output is File 2, which prints File 1 with the new summed values in $2 whereever matches in $1 occurred. Any assistance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in one:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {             # store the file1 to a hash and add to its elements
    a[$1]=$2
    next
}
($1 in a) {
    a[$1]+=$2
}
END {
    for(i in a)
        print i,a[i]  # print in no particular order
}' file1 filea fileb
```

Output:

```
1 0.3
2 1.2
3 0.4
4 1
```