# Matching multiple files with numbers and excluding one of the files by number

Tags: bash, awk

I have a range of files, sorted according to number (File1.txt, File2.txt, File3.txt, etc.), that I am running a loop over in my script as input for awk code. I can pattern match these as

```
awk ... file[1-$i].txt >> output
```

I would however like to exclude a file within that range, such as

```
file$v.txt
```

#### goal

I am looking for something like

```
awk ... file[1-!$v-$i].txt >> output
```

where I match every file from 1-$i, skipping over the file with $v.

---

I have tried various inputs from composite pattern matching as described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching), but I could not get the syntax to work for me.

Does anyone know how to do composite pattern matching like this? Thank you.

---

#### Sample inputs

On request, here are my files:

file.1.dat

```
29.078306 0.00676358
29.223592 0.00309192
30.297306 0.0174575
30.478883 0.132458
30.503705 0.118951
30.512891 0.0705088
31.945900 0.00408244
32.321011 0.00258023
32.894037 0.00407912
32.916263 0.00330154
34.594139 0.00874524
34.849178 0.0195172
34.884655 0.00547378
34.967403 0.00308369
35.325397 0.00818193
```

file.2.dat

```
25.970535 0.0979715
26.913976 0.00593039
29.078306 0.0984052
29.223592 0.00271504
30.236632 0.013818
30.478883 0.0347606
30.503705 0.102369
30.512891 0.0409633
31.714064 0.0242958
31.902306 0.0510168
32.715764 0.0146584
34.952965 0.00484555
35.190790 0.0114201
35.360372 0.0033089
35.575199 0.00282864
38.184618 0.00551692
```

file.3.dat

```
31.591771 0.0126916
32.059389 0.0605918
32.299959 0.122618
32.890418 0.0058495
32.962536 0.00492958
33.646214 0.0705359
33.679538 0.120592
```

file.4.dat

```
25.636267 0.00398174
27.848542 0.00485739
28.269278 0.0174401
29.418886 0.00409613
31.313212 0.203932
31.945900 0.00259743
32.256620 0.00325607
32.299959 0.0325366
33.461363 0.0798633
33.646214 0.0516498
33.679538 0.12871
```

file.5.dat

```
29.767600 0.00777448
32.299959 0.00777995
34.849178 0.0305844
34.884655 0.0126815
34.930799 0.0546924
34.952965 0.0711241
```

#### Awk Code

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$1]=$2
    next
}
($1 in a) {
    a[$1]+=$2
}
END {
    for(i in a)
        print i,a[i]
}' file.4.dat file.[1-5].dat >| test.out
```

This code does the following:

1. Matches file.4.dat to file.1.dat, file.2.dat ... file.5.dat, based on the value in field 1 ($1).
2. Whereever a match in $1 is found, it adds $2 to file.4.dat $2 in the matching row.
3. test.out prints file.4.dat, with $2 being equal to a sum of $2 from matching $1 rows.

A simple example of what I am trying to do was asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55006777/how-to-add-two-columns-from-three-different-files-with-reference-to-matching-val), which is where I have the awk code from.

#### Goal

My goal is to have the following line in my output:

```
33.679538 0.249302
```

among other correctly matched lines, but this line is my current test to see if it works. Right now, I have:

```
33.679538 0.378012
```

as a result of file.4.dat being added to itself in the awk code, since I cannot exclude it in my 2nd argument for input file.

#### Summary of Problems

My awk code is reading all of my input files, and I need to exclude 1 of the files in order to obtain the right output.

Ultimately, I have to input each of my 5 files individually against the other 4 files in the awk code above. In the future, the number of files will be variable, so I cannot just type the file names in my script. For now, if I can solve this at least for fewer than 10 files, it would be a major help.

Comment: Yes, we could mention multiple Input_file(s) in this fashion. Could you please post samples of files along with expected output too in your post and let us knwo then.

Comment: `[1-$i]` isn't a numeric range like you might be thinking of -- for example, `[1-30]` matches a single digit, either `0`, `1`, `2` and `3`, because it treats `1-3` and `0` as the two elements establishing a single-character pattern.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 okay I will.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy For now, I am only working with $i < 10, so maybe this won't be an issue?

Comment: Frankly, it might make more sense to filter after the fact: `shopt -s extglob`, then `files=( ); for file in file+([[:digit:]]).txt; do fileNum=${file//[![:digit:]]/}; (( fileNum < i )) && (( fileNum != v )) || continue; files+=( "$file" ); done`, and then you can `awk ... "${files[@]}"` to pass the list through.

Comment: @Blaisem: Perhaps you could explain your whole requirement, running one instance of `awk` for each of your multiple files seems a lot. Perhaps it could be simplified

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have edited my question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I may have to rewrite my script around this if no other solution is possible. Thank you.

Comment: @Inian I have edited to add this information. Please let me know if I can add more to help out.

Comment: Ahh -- so you could just have *awk* skip a file it's already seen, rather than needing the shell to do that at all.

Comment: @Inian, `>|` as a means to override `noclobber` is in bash; see the REDIRECTION section of the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this in `awk`, by identifying the first file you are using for reference and ignoring that for subsequent processing using `nextfile` option (requires GNU version) which skips processing the file for subsequent processing. Going by this logic, you should place the reference file, e.g. `file.4.dat` in your input as the first argument in the file list.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ ignoreFile = ARGV[1] }
NR==FNR {
    a[$1]=$2
    next
}
FILENAME == ignoreFile { nextfile }
($1 in a) {
    a[$1]+=$2
}
END {
    for(i in a)
        print i,a[i]
}' file.4.dat file.[1-5].dat >| test.out
```

OP wanted to know if they can build a pattern list of filenames that can be generated from the shell and used. It can be done but considering the relatively simpler option available from `nextfile`, this might look complex.

From your understanding you have `n` files and one of them would be used as a reference file. I would prefer using [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) feature of the `bash` shell to include all the files except the reference. For e.g. I'm creating files `file1..10` for explaining this

```
touch file{1..10}
exclude=3
```

The extended shell options are set using `shopt` built-in

```
shopt -s extglob
list=(!(file"$exclude"))
```

Now print the array using `declare -p list` to see the list of files with just the reference file excluded. Now use the array in your `awk` as below. The array expansion `"${list[@]}"` results in all the files excluded you generated above.

```
awk ... file"$exclude" "${list[@]}"
```

Comment: This has worked for me. Thanks so much! For the sake of future readers searching according to the topic of my question, is it not possible to specify a pattern list of matching file names while excluding one pattern from the list?

Comment: @Blaisem : Yes you could build an array of files and exclude that one file. I can update the answer tomorrow for the sake your willingness to know! :)

Answer (score 1):

To skip a file you just set `ARGV[its position in the arg list]` to null. e.g.:

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file3

$ grep . file*
file1:x
file2:y
file3:z

$ awk 'BEGIN{ARGV[2]=""} {print FILENAME, $0}' file*
file1 x
file3 z
```

or you can remove the "bad" file by name rather than order in the arg list if you prefer:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{for (i in ARGV) if (ARGV[i]=="file2") ARGV[i]=""} {print FILENAME, $0}' file*
file1 x
file3 z

$ awk 'BEGIN{bad["file2"]; for (i in ARGV) if (ARGV[i] in bad) ARGV[i]=""} {print FILENAME, $0}' file*
file1 x
file3 z

$ awk '
    BEGIN {
        split("file2 file3",tmp); for (i in tmp) bad[tmp[i]]
        for (i in ARGV) if (ARGV[i] in bad) ARGV[i]=""
    }
    {print FILENAME, $0}
' file*
file1 x
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone don't want to use OR don't have `nextfile` in its system then following could help.

```
awk -v ignore="file.4.dat" '
FNR==1{
    no_parse=""
}
FNR==NR {
    a[$1]=$2
    next
}
FILENAME == ignore{
    no_parse=1
}
no_parse{
    next
}
($1 in a) {
    a[$1]+=$2
}
END {
    for(i in a)
        print i,a[i]
}' file.4.dat file.[1-5].dat >| test.out
```

Created a variable named `ignore` and we could mention Input_file named which we need to ignore there, once that Input_file turn comes for parsing I have set a flag named `no_parse` to TRUE in that  case that specific Input_file's no contents will be read(since `next` is used to skip all further statements)

Comment: @Blaisem, Request you to kindly check this one too and let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Using pipelined awks. You have to give the last file as reference (here->4)

```
awk ' $(NF+1)=FILENAME' file.[1-3].dat file.5.dat file.4.dat |  
   awk ' { a[$1]+=$2; $2=a[$1] } /file.4.dat/ && NF-- '
```

with the given files

```
$ awk ' $(NF+1)=FILENAME' file.[1-3].dat file.5.dat file.4.dat |  
      awk ' { a[$1]+=$2; $2=a[$1] } /file.4.dat/ && NF-- '
25.636267 0.00398174
27.848542 0.00485739
28.269278 0.0174401
29.418886 0.00409613
31.313212 0.203932
31.945900 0.00667987
32.256620 0.00325607
32.299959 0.162935
33.461363 0.0798633
33.646214 0.122186
33.679538 0.249302

$
```